# Temporary ASP.NET Files - duplicate file problem

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-3.5, web-applications

I get an error when ever I replace a user control, or dll on th website. The solution is to stop iis and delete the contents of the folder, obviously not ideal to stop the site.

I read that this might be caused by class names being reused, as in when you make a copy of a control and add it to the solution.

Is it typical for this folder to be used, how can I avoid the site crashing whenever I make a change

Running on IIS7.0, ASP.NET 3.5

Comment: which folder are you referring to?

Comment: C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: Also, what version of VS are you using?

Comment: error is along these lines
exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ops\d43d728c\9ce9baf2\App_Web_8llt2hi-.dll' and 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ops\d43d728c\9ce9baf2\App_Web_winusoz8.dll' 

Web App hosted on IIS7.0 adn 3.5 framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this problem if I update DLLs and don't clear out the BIN folder, because of the way my code is setup. For example, if I am using version 3.0.1 of a DLL and I add version 3.5.0 of that DLL, it causes conflicts.

As far as a solution, I would agree with the first answer though, which is to have a dev server and a live one, and publish up, although it may not be ideal for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

you should separate development from production, and *publish* from dev to the prod iis.

btw, in case you actually have 2 classes with the same name, compilation should fail this way.

Answer (score 1):

Use publish to publish the site, consider precompiling. The temporary folder is where resources compiled on the fly are cached.

Faking a web.config update to generate recompilation might also work as opposed to IIS restart? Though not ideal.